# Is a static boolean a reference type in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, reference, boolean

I'm making some switches. In my MenuScene class there's some booleans that are static variables, booleans, to represent the states of these switches.

Are these addressable as reference types, so I can be sure that other objects are able to change their state with a unique reference to them?

The dream, in my dreamy pseudo code, I'm hoping changes to `iAmOn` impact the state of `myButtonABC_state`

```
class MenuScene {        
        static var myButtonABC_state: Bool = false
        static var myButtonXYZ_state: Bool = false

     override onDidMoveToView {

        let buttonABC = Button(withState: MenuScene.myButtonABC_state)
        let buttonXYZ = Button(withState: MenuScene.myButtonXYZ_state)
       }
    }
```

In a button class

```
class Button {

var iAmOn: Bool = false

    init(withState state: Bool){
        iAmOn = state
    }

    override onTouchesBegun(... etc...){
        if iAmOn { iAMOn = false }
        else { iAmOn = true} 
    }

}
```

Comment: You should update your question with some relevant code. Have you done any tests to see what results you get?

Comment: @rmaddy I think he / she is not quite sure all of the terminology in what asking :) 

Confused, See my answer for some clarity (I hope!)

Comment: No, @maddy, have not run any tests. have updated question to show what I'm hoping happens. Don't know how to make it so.

Comment: @maddy, quick question... once a `bool` is wrapped in a class, and referenced as being a property of that class, is that a reference, even though it's a boolean (which is a struct/value type underneath) because it's become a reference to the class first, and the property second?

Comment: @maddy, I'm running something as per the included code in the question, and it doesn't work... the value isn't changing in the static var, only locally in iAmOn, inside the Button() instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Bool` is a struct in Swift; structs are value types. It doesn't matter if it's `static var`, `class var`, `let`, `var`, etc., the type is what matters--so no, `Bool` is value type.

I think you are not 100% on all of the terminology (mostly because Apple doesn't really cover it much in documentation as usual, lol).

There are "Swift Types" (Bool, Int, your classes/structs, etc), and "Variable/Constant Types" (which hold data in a memory register, such as references or actual-values), as well as "Memory Register Write/Read Types" (variable vs vonstant, mutable vs immutable, `var` vs `let`).

Don't be frustrated.. It's a bit confusing for everyone... Especially at first and without great documentation. (I tried learning C++ pointers early age and it was way over my head).

Here's a good reference material: (towards the bottom)
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html

Basically, if you want to hold a reference to something, you have to use a Reference Type memory register. This means using a class *instance* Static makes no difference:

```
/* Test1: */

struct Hi {
    static var sup = "hey"
}

var z = Hi.sup
Hi.sup = "yo"

print(z) // prints "hey"

/* Test 2: */

class Hi2 {
    static var sup = "hey"
}

var z2 = Hi2.sup
Hi2.sup = "yo"

print(z2) // Prints "hey"
```

If you feel like you *need* a pointer to something that isn't inside of a class, then you can use `UnsafeMutablePointer` or something like that from OBJc code.

Or, you can wrap a bool inside of a class object (which are always references).

```
final class RefBool {
   var val: Bool
   init(_ value: Bool) { val = value }
}
```

And here is some interesting behavior for reference types using `let`:

```
let someBool: RefBool

someBool = RefBool(true)
someBool = RefBool(false) // wont compile.. someBool is a `let`
someBool.val = false      // will compile because of reference type and member is `var`
```

Comment: @AlexanderMomchilov thanks alex I was still working on formatting once I realized that I missed the point of the Q and was trying to update info :)

Comment: Just to clarify, there is no `NSUnsafeMutablePointer` Objective-C type.  `UnsafeMutablePointer` is a pure Swift type used when C pointers are bridged to Swift.  But they can also be used in pure Swift as well (`alloc`/`free`, etc.), but you really need a good reason to get that low level.

Comment: @JAL you know I thought it was just `UnsafeMutablePointer` a regular type but then I just threw the NS on there on a whim. I should have checked first.. I will update. Thanks!!

Comment: @Confused, see my first code block, the `z2` example. You want `iAmOn` VALUE to be a REFERENCE to `MenuScene.myButtonState`. So, `var iAmOn = MenuScene.myButtonState`

THen you will get what you want as I showed in my block

Comment: how can a `let` assigned to the state (boolean) be changeable?

Comment: @Confused, I seem to be in contact with you frequently. Would you like to chat for a few min somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128592/discussion-between-confused-and-fluidity).

Comment: @Confused I'm in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127579/swift if you want I can tell you a few things

Comment: In your second example, z2, and as per your comment yesterday, I have passed a reference to this static var as a parameter into a function that creates a new object based on this state, and then creates an internal reference to this passed in reference to the static var. But changing the value of this reference to true/false does not change the original static var's value. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Confused use `inout` in your parameter which should do the trick

Comment: As soon as someBool.val is defined as having a type of Bool, in the parameter list of the function declaration and then used in the definition, it's a value, not the pointer to the someBool.val container for the value.

Comment: @Confused I'm honestly not a swift guru by any means (ask Martin R or someone) but functions try to copy (value) whenever possible (in my limited understanding). So that is why your "reference" wasn't working without `inout`, because Swift doesn't have a strict pointer / reference system (that I'm aware of) outside of the ObjectiveC types

Comment: @Confused I can say that if you put an object of a class like `SKNode` as a parameter, you *will* get a reference even without `inout`...

Comment: Yes, I know. Anything that's a class type gets passed as a class type, because that's stipulated, and because it's a reference. But these simple little booleans are deceptively tricky to pass references off: for me. I've had no luck with any of these techniques. Everything is passing the value, not the pointer/reference.

Comment: If you need a chuckle, have a look at my convoluted attempts to get the activity to work as I want, but not in the way I'd like... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745099/how-to-pass-a-reference-to-a-boolean-rather-than-its-value